# Android App for Rails App storing Sessions/Cookie

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, session-cookies

I am new to both Android and Rails. I built a simple Rails app to log in to post comments and leave replies to others' comments as well. I am trying to see how to build a native Android app to respond to this Rails app and have come across a question with sessions/cookie.

In order for me to build a native android app that can allow a user to log in and browse through the rails app, do I have to write a code that receives cookie from the rails app and store it in android sqlite database? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to load a view in HTML (an embedded browser), or render a view on the device using the native controls?  If you're doing the former, surely Android already handles all this for you, just like a WebView in an iPhone app does?

If you're doing the latter, you should build an API that uses something like OAuth for authentication, rather than maintaining a session cookie.  This approach means that you store a pair of (revokable) OAuth credentials on the device and that you don't need to work with the user's username/password.

I'm not sure on what your end goal is here.

Comment: Thanks d11wtq. The end goal is to build a native android app to do what my rails app currently does through regular browser. I am able to do it through the android browser as well, but I am assuming that the android browser saves the cookie and creates session the way rails app is built to do. I want to do all of this in the native android app instead of feeling like it's using a browser. I was wondering if when the rails app creates a session, the android app is supposed to receive cookie and save in the sqlite3 db of the phone so that the rails app knows that this user has logged in. Thanks

Comment: Don't use sessions... develop an API that uses OAuth.  Read up on it ;)  If you do insist on using sessions (which are intended for web browsers, not for APIs, then you'll have to manage `Cookie:` and `Set-Cookie:` headers.  Basically it sounds like you're trying to do something the wrong way.  There's an gem aptly named 'oauth' that will do the hard work for you ;)